# How to make Initial avatar image in registration process in laravel 8 without any package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

Recently I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32xlHYdJ3Ug but in the final my Laravel Version (8.80.0) doesn't have the RegisterController.php only Register**ed**Controller.php. Soo I have "Call to undefined function imagecreate()" error, How could I fix that?